# Create a dropdown list from a list in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drop-down-menu

I want to create a list of all color properties in my material.
And make a dropdown list from this list so that the user can choose the option he wants.

I made this code with the help of artificial intelligence, and by the way it worked once, but when I deleted it and put it on another model, it didn't work anymore:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class testScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material myMaterial;
    public List<string> colorPropertyNames;
    public string selectedColorPropertyName;
    
    [ContextMenu("Test")]
    void Test()
    {
        colorPropertyNames = new List<string>();

        int propertyCount = ShaderUtil.GetPropertyCount(myMaterial.shader);

        for (int i = 0; i < propertyCount; i++)
        {
            string propertyName = ShaderUtil.GetPropertyName(myMaterial.shader, i);
            ShaderUtil.ShaderPropertyType propertyType = ShaderUtil.GetPropertyType(myMaterial.shader, i);

            if (propertyType == ShaderUtil.ShaderPropertyType.Color)
            {
                colorPropertyNames.Add(propertyName);
            }
        }

        foreach (string colorPropertyName in colorPropertyNames)
        {
            Debug.Log("Color Property Name: " + colorPropertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

and this script for editor:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(TestScriptEditor))]
public class TestScriptEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty myMaterialProperty;
    private SerializedProperty colorPropertyNamesProperty;
    private SerializedProperty selectedColorPropertyNameProperty;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        myMaterialProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("myMaterial");
        colorPropertyNamesProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("colorPropertyNames");
        selectedColorPropertyNameProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("selectedColorPropertyName");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(myMaterialProperty);

        // Get the list of color property names
        var colorPropertyNames = new string[colorPropertyNamesProperty.arraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < colorPropertyNamesProperty.arraySize; i++)
        {
            colorPropertyNames[i] = colorPropertyNamesProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).stringValue;
        }

        // Get the selected color property index
        int selectedColorIndex = Mathf.Max(0,
            System.Array.IndexOf(colorPropertyNames, selectedColorPropertyNameProperty.stringValue));

        // Display the dropdown menu
        selectedColorIndex = EditorGUILayout.Popup("Color Property", selectedColorIndex, colorPropertyNames);

        // Update the selected color property name
        if (selectedColorIndex >= 0 && selectedColorIndex < colorPropertyNames.Length)
        {
            selectedColorPropertyNameProperty.stringValue = colorPropertyNames[selectedColorIndex];
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a simple typo: You used `typeof(TestScriptEditor)` but it should be the type this editor is for so `typeof(testScript)` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed using this method. For now, I don't know if this method is standard or not! AI made this too!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class testScript : MonoBehaviour
{
     public Material myMaterial;
     public List<string> colorPropertyNames;
     public string selectedColorPropertyName;

     [ContextMenu("Test")]
     void Test()
     {
         colorPropertyNames = new List<string>();

         int propertyCount = ShaderUtil.GetPropertyCount(myMaterial.shader);

         for (int i = 0; i < propertyCount; i++)
         {
             string propertyName = ShaderUtil.GetPropertyName(myMaterial.shader, i);
             ShaderUtil.ShaderPropertyType propertyType = ShaderUtil.GetPropertyType(myMaterial.shader, i);

             if (propertyType == ShaderUtil.ShaderPropertyType.Color)
             {
                 colorPropertyNames.Add(propertyName);
             }
         }

         foreach (string colorPropertyName in colorPropertyNames)
         {
             Debug.Log("Color Property Name: " + colorPropertyName);
         }
     }
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(testScript))]
public class TestScriptEditor : Editor
{
     private SerializedProperty myMaterialProperty;
     private SerializedProperty colorPropertyNamesProperty;
     private SerializedProperty selectedColorPropertyNameProperty;

     private void OnEnable()
     {
         myMaterialProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("myMaterial");
         colorPropertyNamesProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("colorPropertyNames");
         selectedColorPropertyNameProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("selectedColorPropertyName");
     }

     public override void OnInspectorGUI()
     {
         serializedObject.Update();

         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(myMaterialProperty);

         // Get the list of color property names
         var colorPropertyNames = new string[colorPropertyNamesProperty.arraySize];
         for (int i = 0; i < colorPropertyNamesProperty.arraySize; i++)
         {
             colorPropertyNames[i] = colorPropertyNamesProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).stringValue;
         }

         // Get the selected color property index
         int selectedColorIndex = Mathf.Max(0,
             System.Array.IndexOf(colorPropertyNames, selectedColorPropertyNameProperty.stringValue));

         // Display the dropdown menu
         selectedColorIndex = EditorGUILayout.Popup("Color Property", selectedColorIndex, colorPropertyNames);

         // Update the selected color property name
         if (selectedColorIndex >= 0 && selectedColorIndex < colorPropertyNames.Length)
         {
             selectedColorPropertyNameProperty.stringValue = colorPropertyNames[selectedColorIndex];
         }

         serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
     }
}
```

Comment: AI-generated solutions are not permitted on Stack Overflow (especially if you cannot break down **WHY** the solution solves the problem)